# How can i return this variable from within a method call?

Tags: javascript

This is a simple question but I'm stumped.

I have the method:

```
    twitter.get('statuses/home_timeline', {screen_name: 'foo'}, function(err,item)     {
    console.log(item);
 });
```

And I want to be able to access the variable `item`

I have tried this:

```
    var twitterFeed = twitter.get('statuses/home_timeline', {screen_name: 'foo'}, function(err, item) {
    return item;
 });


console.log("This should be something: ", twitterFeed);
```

but every time, the output of the console is `undefined`.

Any tips on how I can access or return the variable `item`, to outside its scope?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check err in the console?

Comment: try printing `console.log(arguments)` and see what you have. maybe you have no "item"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing much about the library you're using, I'll assume it's a standard AJAX call. Then the function you're giving to `twitter.get` will almost surely not be called by the time `twitter.get` has returned. Rather, it will have specified that it would like that function to be called *eventually*, and you can't predict when that is. It therefore becomes impossible to reliably do any work with `item` immediately after `twitter.get` has returned.

You have two options at that point:

Either do the work you want to do with item *inside* the function.

E.G. (the right way)

```
var twitterFeed = twitter.get('statuses/home_timeline', {screen_name: 'foo'}, function(err, item) {
    doStuffWithItem(item);
});
```

or if you want to keep the value around in some namespace, you can do

```
var item;
var twitterFeed = twitter.get('statuses/home_timeline', {screen_name: 'foo'}, function(err, it) {
    item = it;
});
```

And then anything in the same scope as `var item` will be able to access the result. *HOWEVER* you will never be able to assume that the value has been put in the variable yet, because you cannot predict when the function has been called. However this is a vaguely sane pattern if, e.g. you want to know the last result found by `twitter.get` or something. You can of course at any time check if `item` has been populated with

```
if(item !== undefined){
    doStuffWithItem(item);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! very clear I really appreciate it